# Jquery scroll menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want a scroll menu like the one in this site: http://wearemanic.com/.

What technique should I use? Is there a plugin out there which provides this functionality? Can you please suggest some key words to google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a plugin to do what they did. If you inspect their website you can see it is custom made. [ruler-scroller.js](http://wearemanic.com/wp-content/themes/manic/js/ruler-scroller.js) is the class they use to scroll over the ruler matching the page. They use jQuery and jQuery.transform for the animation.

I advise you to look at their code and try to make your own scroller. Don't start big, try something small first. For example how I would start making a scroller.

1. Start by making a box on the left side of the page move towards the bottom on a mouse click.
2. Make functions you can call to make the ruler go to a certain position
3. Try to make the ruler move according to a moving page.
4. Etc

Don't start to big, start small and add functionality by small steps.